# Reccomended way to acces a single row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I often want to select a single row of a Pandas DataFrame using multiple conditions.

For further processing it is usefull to acces it as a Series or Dict, NOT as a 1xW DataFrame.

I can do it like this:

```
r = df.loc[ (df['col1'] == v1) & (df['col2'] == v2) ]
if len(r.index) != 1:
  raise ValueError(...)
r = r.iloc[0]
```

This feels a bit clunky. Is there a better, reccomended way?

Comment: Do `'col1'`'and `'col2'` form a unique key for your DataFrame?

Comment: @ALollz yes, in combination with a 3rd column

Comment: Do you ever need/use the `'col1'` and `'col2'` part of the returned Series, or are they mainly just used for selection? If you don't need them after I'd say a MultiIndex is the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the builtin accessors will do what you want. You can build your own accessor and monkey-patch it in:

```
def get(df, **kwargs):
    cond = [True] * df.shape[0]
    for col, value in kwargs.items():
        cond &= df[col] == value

    result = df[cond]
    if result.shape[0] > 1:
        raise ValueError('Key must be unique')
    return result.iloc[0]

pd.DataFrame.get = get

# Usage
df.get(col1=..., col2=..., col3=...)
```

This is relatively slow, however, so don't call it in a tight loop.